# How to catch the MulterError: Unexpected field when the number of the files exceeds the limit?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer

I want to be able to detect the `MulterError: Unexpected field` when uploading more files than the set limit.

Currently I have the following code in my `app.js` Node.js app, but it doesn't catch this error. What could be wrong?

```
var multer = require('multer')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './tmsap')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    },
})
var upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage,
    onError:  function(err, next) {
       console.log('Upload Error')
       res.error('There was an error when uploading your files. Perhaps, you attached too many? Please, try again.')
       res.redirect('back')
    }
})


app.post(
    '/import/files',
    upload.array('uploadedFiles', 50),
    imports.submit
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a callback to the multer middleware that allows you to check for errors:

```
app.post('/import/files', (req, res, next) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError && err.code === "LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE") {
            // handle multer file limit error here
        } else if (err) {}
        // handle other errors... }
        else {
            // make sure to call next() if all was well
            next();
        }
    })
}, imports.submit);
```

Comment: Had a little bug with the parentheses, should be fixed now.